# java - images in javafx

Tags: java, image, javafx

I am still pretty new to java and i am still learning. I have never used images before so it is possible if I can have help add a image. I am not that sure what needs to be done in order to add one. Thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFvGq.png)

here is the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

class User {
    private StringProperty order = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public String getOrder() {
        return order.get();
    }

    public void setOrder(String order) {
        this.order.set(order);
    }

    public StringProperty orderProperty() {
        return order;
    }
}

public class pizza extends Application {

    private User user = new User();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Pizza System");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("place order");
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setBottom(btn);
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
             public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                btn.setText("Order has been placed. Please wait at least 30 minutes.");
                }
        });





        RadioButton tomatoButton = new RadioButton("Tomato");
        RadioButton pepperButton = new RadioButton("Pepper");
        RadioButton mushroomButton = new RadioButton("Mushrooms");

        ChoiceBox<String> pizzaType = new ChoiceBox<String>();
        pizzaType.getItems().addAll("", "Small", "Medium", "Large");
        pizzaType.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

       HBox topHBox = new HBox(15.0, tomatoButton, pepperButton, mushroomButton, pizzaType);

        // create custom Binding that binds selection of radio buttons and choice box
        StringBinding orderBinding = createOrderBinding(tomatoButton.selectedProperty(), pepperButton.selectedProperty(), mushroomButton.selectedProperty(), pizzaType.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
        // bind orderBinding to orderProperty of User
        user.orderProperty().bind(orderBinding);

        TextArea orderArea = new TextArea();
        // bind orderProperty of User to textProperty of TextArea
        orderArea.textProperty().bindBidirectional(user.orderProperty());

       BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(topHBox);
        root.setCenter(orderArea);
        root.setBottom(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public StringBinding createOrderBinding(BooleanProperty tomato, BooleanProperty pepper, BooleanProperty mushroom, ReadOnlyObjectProperty<String> selectedPizzaType) {
        StringBinding binding = new StringBinding() {
            {
                // bind 4 provided properties.
                super.bind(tomato, pepper, mushroom, selectedPizzaType);
            }

            @Override
            protected String computeValue() {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Pizza content:\n");

                if (tomato.get())
                    sb.append("\tTomato\n");
                if (pepper.get())
                    sb.append("\tPepper\n");
                if (mushroom.get())
                    sb.append("\tMushroom\n");

                sb.append("Pizza type:\n").append("\t" + selectedPizzaType.get());
                return sb.toString();
            }
        };
        return binding;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to place the image? I do not see an [Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) defined in your code.

Comment: I want to place in the center on the right

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX uses an [Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) to load the image file and it has a node called [ImageView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) to place that image on the screen graph.

Considering that the image is present at the same location as your class file, you can use this:

```
// Load Image
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource("image.jpg").toExternalForm());
// Set the Image on the ImageView
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
// specify a size
imageView.setFitWidth(200);
imageView.setFitHeight(200);
// Place ImageView in a container
root.setRight(imageView);
```